# Переход в начало консольной программы на С вместо завершения программы

Tags: c

Есть консольная программа на С, в ней вводимое с помощью оператора `scanf` число преобразуется по некоторой формуле и выводится результат. После этого по нажатию Enter программа завершается. Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию клавиши Enter или любой другой программа не завершалась а начиналась заново, с ввода нового данного?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double N, X;
    printf("Enter N\n");
    scanf("%lF",&N);
    X=(1000*N-120)/180;
    printf("Extraction %lF\n", X);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for(;;)
    {    
        double N, X;
        printf("Enter N: ");
        if (scanf("%lf",&N) != 1) break;
        X=(1000*N-120)/180;
        printf("Extraction %lf\n", X);
        getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если все значения диапазона нужны? Сигналы надо обрабатывать, сигналы... (если система POSIX-совместимая)

Comment: @0andriy Не понял ваше упоминание о диапазоне? Вводите xnj хотите - лишь бы в рамках `double`...

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал, примерно, так

```
while ( 1 )
{
    double N, X;
    printf("Enter N\n");
    if ( scanf("%lF",&N) != 1 || N == 0 ) break;
    X=(1000*N-120)/180;
    printf("Extraction %lF\n", X);
}
```

Здесь выход из цикла происходит, либо когда пользователь прервал ввод, или когда введен ноль. Второе условие, то есть сравнение с нулем, вы можете заменить на сравнение с каким-нибудь другим значением по вашему усмотрению, завершающим цикл. Или просто выходить из цикла, когда пользователь просто прервал цикл, то есть

```
    if ( scanf("%lF",&N) != 1 ) break;
```

Вы также можете включить заголовок `<stdbool.h>`, и тогда цикл можно записать в виде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        double N, X;

        printf("Enter N: ");

        if ( scanf("%lF", &N) != 1 || N == 0 ) break;

        X=(1000*N-120)/180;
        printf("Extraction %lF\n", X);
    }
}
```